Rider showing Count and Length property for MatchCollection
Consider this code:
var matches = new Regex("pattern").Matches("something");
matches. // trigger auto completion

In this case, auto completion shows me a Count and a Length property, where the Length property is really the Count property. How can I turn off this behaviour? I find it more confusing then helpful.


I've filled the ticket about this issue in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-497257/Rider-showing-Count-and-Length-property-for-MatchCollection
You are welcome to comment on it and follow up to receive updates.
Thank you!
